# Is there any method to pass data from one browser to another browser like chrome to firefox

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, web

I have two different pages one is for Admin and another is for User. Admin page name is **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
            * {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            body{
                background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                text-align: center;
            }
            .card{
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                height: 100%;
                padding: 100px;
            }

            h2{
                margin: 0 50px;
                font-size: 50px;
            }
            button{
                background-color: #ff9100;
                border: none;
                color: white;
                padding: 15px 32px;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 16px;
                margin: 4px 2px;
                cursor: pointer;
                border-radius: 25px;
            }
            button:hover{
                background-color: rgb(206, 206, 206);
                color: #ff9100;
                border-color: #000 ;
            }
        
        </style>
        
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Live Users in Mall</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Live Users in Mall</h1>
            <div class="card">
                <!--
                    Rather than using `inline` function calls it is 
                    preferable to assign an external event listener.
                    You can easily use the same event handler to 
                    perform both increment and decrement tasks.
                    
                    To aid that the buttons were assign a dataset
                    attribute which is analysed in the click handler.
                -->
                <button data-action='decrement'>-</button>
                <h2>0</h2>
                <button data-action='increment'>+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        
            // Establish the communication channel - this can be (nearly) any name 
            // but the same name is needed for the listeners.
            
            let oChan=new BroadcastChannel( 'tabs' );
            let h2=document.querySelector('div.card h2');
            
            
            // simple function to send a payload of your design
            const sendmessage=function( data ){
                let payload={ 'data':data };
                oChan.postMessage( payload );
            };
    
    
            // fetch the data from localStorage or set as zero
            let data=localStorage.getItem('key');
            if( data == null )data=0;
            else data=Number( data );
            
            h2.innerHTML=data;
            
            
            // assign an event listener for both buttons
            document.querySelectorAll('button[data-action]').forEach( bttn=>{
                bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                    switch( this.dataset.action ){
                        case 'increment':data++;break;
                        case 'decrement':data--;break;
                    }
                    
                    //update storage
                    localStorage.setItem('key',data);
                    
                    // send the message to the "other" page
                    sendmessage( data );
                    
                    // update local display
                    h2.innerHTML=data;
                });
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Another page name is **showdata.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Show Live Data</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Users Present in Mall</h3>
        <h2>0</h2>  
        <script>
            // establish listener on same channel
            let oChan=new BroadcastChannel( 'tabs' );
                oChan.addEventListener('message',(e)=>{
                    // process the messages as they arrive
                    document.querySelector('h2').innerHTML=e.data.data
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My project contents two different users so they will open sites in two different browsers. But **I want to show admin(index.html) updated data from 1st browser to users(showdata.html) side in 2nd browser**. Is this possible? If yes then please give me solution for this

Comment: Do you mean websockets like https://pusher.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I found it. I've solved the issue by using a backend database and WebSockets to transfer data between tabs in the same browser.